# ignoresafearea is not properly working in pro max devices using swift

Tags: swiftui

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
    
        ZStack{
            Image("background").ignoresSafeArea([.all])
        }
    }
}
```

tried as [.bottom,.top,..leading,.trailing]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add [`resizable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/image/resizable(capinsets:resizingmode:)) modifier on your `Image` to resize an image to fit its space.

```
Image("background")
    .resizable()
    .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
```

If it still not covering the full screen then add [`aspectRatio`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/aspectratio(_:contentmode:)-771ow) modifier after `resizable`.

```
Image("background")
    .resizable()
    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
    .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will Surely Work with latest iOS & IpadOS
instead of just ignoresSafeArea([.all]) we can use frame with UIScreen as shown below:

```
struct ContentView: View {
 var body: some View {
     ZStack{
        Image("background")
        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width ,
                   height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height
            )
        .ignoresSafeArea(.all,edges: .all
    }
}
```

}